Wireless Communication: detecting if a bit 0 changed to 1
I am new in wireless communication, and now I have a 0/1 string like 0010000 (only one bit 1) and wanna send it to the receiver wirelessly. Am I able to detect if the receiver get this string correctly, i.e., getting 0010000 exactly. I wanna make sure 0 (or 1) is not changed to 1 (or 0), and if no way to confirm that, what kind of technology is available to detect any changes?
Any idea about this? I would really appreciate it.

CRC

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction
